# jQuery full calendar resource view restrict past slots

Tags: jquery, date, events, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using jQuery FullCalendar plugin for Room Booking. For this, I'm getting both Resources and Event list from server code as JSON array.

Here is my code:

```
function LoadBookings() {

    var rooms = [];
    var events = [];

    var s = $("#hdnStudio").val();
    var u = $("#hdnUnit").val();
    var f = $("#hdnFloor").val();
    var r = $("#hdnRoom").val();

    if ($('#calendar').length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/RoomBooking/Events',
            data: { studio: s, unit: u, floor: f },
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                $.each(result.events, function (i, v) {
                    if (v.IsAllDayEvent) {
                        events.push({ id: v.Id, resourceId: v.RoomId, start: moment(v.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), end: moment(v.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), title: v.Title });
                    }
                    else {
                        events.push({ id: v.Id, resourceId: v.RoomId, start: moment(v.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"), end: moment(v.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"), title: v.Title });
                    }
                });
                $.each(result.rooms, function (i, v) {
                    rooms.push({ id: v.Id, title: v.Name, eventColor: v.EventColor });
                });

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    schedulerLicenseKey: "GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source",
                    editable: false, // enable draggable events
                    aspectRatio: 1.8,
                    resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
                    slotEventOverlap: false,
                    minTime: "09:30:00",
                    maxTime: "23:30:00",
                    scrollTime: '09:30', // undo default 6am scrollTime
                    header: {
                        left: 'today prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'timelineDay,agendaWeek,month,listWeek'
                    },
                    defaultView: 'timelineDay',
                    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
                    height: 500,
                    resources: rooms,
                    events: events,
                    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {

                        var url = "/RoomBooking/Create?roomId=" + resourceObj.id + "&sDate=" + date.format();
                        $("#room-booking-modal .modal-content").load(url, function () {
                            $("#room-booking-modal").modal({ show: true });
                        });
                    },
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        var url = "/RoomBooking/Edit?id=" + calEvent.id;
                        $("#room-booking-modal .modal-content").load(url, function () {
                            $("#room-booking-modal").modal({ show: true });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here, I wanted to restrict users to book the rooms if slot time is lesser than current time. How can I achieve this?

I'm using moment.js as well for date comparisons.

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and you should not use it (it causes a poor user experience by locking the browser during the AJAX request), also eventually it will stop working at all as browsers remove the feature. In any case you don't need it - you're handling the response properly. You can remove that line.

Comment: Anyway, normally you should create events with [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) not `dayClick`. Then you can use [selectConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint) to set a date/time range where events are allowed to be entered.

Comment: But if you don't want to move away from using dayClick, then when dayClick runs you can check the `date` variable to see whether it's before the current date or not (you can use the momentJS isBefore() function for that).